# "Power On Reset" on CD4026 IC

Tags: digital-logic, cmos

I know it's needed to connect a capacitor from Vdd to Vss on 40XX IC's. Is it also useful on a CD4026 counter to connect the reset pin to one end of the capacitor to reset the IC to zero when powered on?

I used the same type of circuit for the CD4060 1 Hz quartz crystal which i'm using for my digital clock. I referred to [this guide](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/123626-making-flasher-timer-oscillator-circuits-using-a-single-chip/)

This schematic is not complete, but notice how I have resistors connected to the ends of the capacitors.. Am I even using these correctly? I will also be using AND gates to reset these CD4026's at different times so really, not having these resistors would simplify my circuit a bit. Would rather not have them if they aren't needed.

[image: schematic]

I found [another guide](https://www.homemade-circuits.com/how-to-understand-ic-4060-pin-outs/) here with another reset circuit. It's slightly different than the first guide.

[image]

And from the [First guide](https://www.brighthubengineering.com/diy-electronics-devices/123626-making-flasher-timer-oscillator-circuits-using-a-single-chip/) I posted.

[image]

Are either of these incorrect and why?

Update: The first guide was confirmed incorrect in the comments. I’m going to test with the second since I don’t have a diode.

Answer (score 4):

Your power on reset circuit doesn't make sense. The reset pin is always tied to ground via the resistor.

This is a conventional power on reset circuit for pulsing the reset pin high at power on to reset a 'reset pin high' chip. When power is first applied, both sides of the discharged capacitor rise to Vdd. Then the capacitor charges through the resistor and its lower plate drops to 0V releasing the chip. The diode prevents the reset pin going more than 0.7V below ground at power down thereby protecting the IC's input.

For a 'reset pin low' IC. The positions of the capacitor and resistor would be swapped and the diode omitted.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fElAYT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

EDIT

Your first guide is incorrect because the RC reset circuit doesn't provide a power-on pulse to the reset pin. The second guide RC reset circuit does.

Your concern about the slowly transitioning reset pin in my original circuit is a valid one and this could cause problems in certain situations. As the capacitor charges, the reset pin falls slowly and this could take the chip in and out of reset multiple times during power up possibly causing glitches at the chip’s outputs if it is being clocked during power up. This may or may not be a problem to you. My circuits below get around this potential problem by including Schmitt triggers to cause a ‘snap’ transition of the reset pin.

[image: RESET CIRCUITS]

The bottom reset circuit is for when there are both ‘reset low’ and ‘reset high’ chips in the circuit.

You can use the top circuit of the three and reset the chip, via one input of the 4093 schmitt nand, whenever you want to.

Comment: I would have thought you would be OK with a much smaller `C2`, maybe 10 nF - any reason for choosing the larger value?

Comment: Larger time constant caters for more slowly rising supply rail.

Comment: Is the author of that guide I linked incorrect? He did not use a diode for his reset circuit.

Comment: @nekomatic The parallel combination of the two capacitors equals the capacitance of the crystal. The oscillator works very reliably. Left it running for days on an o-scope and hasn’t budged. I’m mostly concerned with wiring the IC’s to reset properly at power on.

Comment: For a 'reset pin low' IC I'd rather keep the diode in parallel to the resistor, for the same reason as for the 'reset pin high' IC: Limit the voltage at Reset to allowed values. -- @StrugglingStudent117 If you *know for sure* that there are built-in diodes in the IC that are capable of taking the discharge current when the supply voltage drops, you may omit the diode.

Comment: @StrugglingStudent117 I'm talking about `C2` in the circuit in this answer. The larger the value, the longer it will take before the IC comes out of the reset state (and I believe if the falling edge of the reset pulse is too slow you may get unexpected behaviour). As James comments though, if `C2` is too small and the supply rail doesn't rise fast enough then the chip might not see an  adequate reset pulse.

Comment: @the busybee good point about the diode still being required for 'reset pin low'.

Comment: Another reason for the diode is to discharge the capacitor quickly when powered off. Without it, a quick power off and on again may not reset the circuit.

Comment: @James could you explain more about discharge current and diode protection? I could not find much online. The datasheet states that input can take -0.5V to Vdd+0.5V
What happens during power off? How does reset pin go below Vss?